# Subring Proof Question

Tags: abstract-algebra

The question reads: "Let $T$ be the ring of all continuous functions from $\Bbb{R}$ to $\Bbb{R}$. Let $S = \{f \in T \mid f (2) = 0\}$. Either prove or disprove that $S$ is a subring of *T*".
(Note: E is "is an element of". Sorry for the poor formatting.)

I know I need to prove that if $b$ and $c$ are elements of $S$, $b+c, -b$ and $bc$ are in $S$, but I'm not sure how to do that for this particular case.

Comment: Please note the $\LaTeX$ formatting I did to your question.

Comment: Some people require that subrings contain $1$.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f,g\in S$ then $(f+g)(2)=f(2)+g(2)=0$ and so on.

Comment: This answer seems to be hinting towards a *yes* answer, yet many authors (I'd say most of them) *require* subrings to contain the same unit of the mother ring in case there is one, and here this isn't fulfilled...